# why does changing of class of a element distorts the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I am trying to change a class of a element and my view gets distorted?
How do I solve it.

I have created the fiddle for the same [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1c2ai/nbtopke1/48/)

Issue Description:

I have a custom textbox. I have a reference value at top left corner of it. 
If I enter value greater or less than the reference value , I show a box asking for reason.

It works perfectly fine, but when I try to add some extra functionality , like changing the color of the div in right top corner of textbox by changing the class of the div , the view is distorted and not as it was expected.

In the fiddle I can commented the code in javascript section at line 73,74,77,78

```
function changeClassOfCommentToRed(divId){
//$("#"+divId).removeClass();
//$("#"+divId).addClass("commentCornerRed");
}
function changeClassOfCommentToGreen(divId){
//$("#"+divId).removeClass();
//$("#"+divId).addClass("commentCornerGreen");
}
```

if I uncomment the above line for extra functionality , I get a distorted view as in following image
[image]

Comment: `<input>` elements cannot have content. That's what the red stuff in jsfiddle is trying to tell you.

Comment: You apply the class to the tooltip, not to the corner.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify which class to remove in your removeClass :

```
removeClass('classToRemove');
```

Comment: `removeClass` receives just the class name, withou the `.` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to remove the classes you want to change:

```
function changeClassOfCommentToRed(divId){
    $("#"+divId).removeClass("commentCornerGreen commentCornerRed");
    $("#"+divId).addClass("commentCornerRed");
}
function changeClassOfCommentToGreen(divId){
    $("#"+divId).removeClass("commentCornerGreen commentCornerRed");
    $("#"+divId).addClass("commentCornerGreen");
}
```

And in your CSS you need to address your arrow pseudo element not the element itself:

```
.commentCornerRed:after {
    ...
}
.commentCornerGreen:after {
    ...
}
```

With this changes, only the color of the arrows is changed, not the color of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what question correctly. I think this `commentCornerRed` class got `width: 0` and `height: 0`. you can have the same properties as `.arrow_box`

```
.commentCornerRed {
     position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ff0000 transparent transparent;
    padding-left: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can make it like this.

```
.commentCornerRed {
    position: absolute;
    background: #bcb476;
    border: 1px solid #08090a;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake. I was passing the wrong id for class name. Got the desired result by passing the right id at line 85 and 87 in javascript section.

changing from

```
function handleCommentBox(event){
if(checkIfReasonSelected(returnIdPrefix(event)+"r1")){
    changeClassOfCommentToGreen(returnIdPrefix(event)+"r1");
    }else{
    changeClassOfCommentToRed(returnIdPrefix(event)+"r1");
    }
}
```

to

```
function handleCommentBox(event){
if(checkIfReasonSelected(returnIdPrefix(event)+"r1")){
    changeClassOfCommentToGreen(returnIdPrefix(event)+"c1");
    }else{
    changeClassOfCommentToRed(returnIdPrefix(event)+"c1");
    }
}
```

solved the problem. Thanks people for helping.